# JavaFX FXML: Expand ScrollPane to Fit height of its Content Pane Until it reahces its MaxHeight property

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I have the following FXML view:

- **VBox**

  - ScrollPane

    - VBox  **buttonsContainer**
  - Button (Adds a new button to **buttonsContainer**)

I want the ScrollPane to **expand** its height to match its `child vbox's height`, until it reaches a certain height [200px for example] then it stops expanding.

I've been playing around for the past 1 hour with the `Min/Pref Viewport Height`, and `Min/Max/Pref Height` properties to achieve this, but nothing worked out.

Is this this possible to do?

**Edit**: Here's a minimal, complete, and verifiable example :

`MainView.fxml`

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="200.0" spacing="5.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MainController">
   <ScrollPane maxHeight="200.0"  VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <VBox fx:id="_buttonsContainer" />
   </ScrollPane>
   <Button fx:id="_btnAddButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
</VBox>
```

`MainController.java`

```
public class MainController implements Initializable{

    @FXML private Button _btnAddButton;
    @FXML private VBox   _buttonsContainer;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        _btnAddButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            addButton();
        });
    }

    private void addButton(){
        _buttonsContainer.getChildren().add(new Button());
    }
}
```

Comment: The obvious choices would be `<ScrollPane maxHeight="200" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" ... />`. Does that not work? If not, can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: @James_D
Yes that doesn't work, I added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```xml
   <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" maxHeight="200.0" minViewportHeight="0.0" minHeight="0.0">
         <VBox fx:id="_buttonsContainer" />
   </ScrollPane>
```

The scroll pane, and its viewport, seem to have some fixed positive minimum height by default.

Comment: It's a little confusing. One would think that the maxHeight property does what is claims to do. 

I tried to avoid doing this through code, because i want as less UI control clutter as possible in my controller, but i guess it's unavoidable.

Comment: @JawnyThompson The `maxHeight` property does appear to do what it claims to do: it sets the maximum height of the scroll pane. It seems the issue is that the scroll pane and viewport have a minimum height. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(VBox.heightProperty());

then add ScrollPane.setMaxHeight(200);  try this

Comment: Looking at this i thought it would work, but it sadly didn't